# Jquery working on 1.7 but not in 1.9.2

Tags: jquery

My code only works with *jQuery 1.7* but my site is now using *1.9.2*. I've tried the migrate plugin but didn't worked out.

The idea is to auto focus one of the fields I have on my page on key press ONLY when no other is focused.

```js
$('body').on('keydown', function() {
    if ($(':focus:not("input")').length) {
        var input = $('input[name="textfield"]');
        if(!input.is(':focus')) {
           input.focus();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- 1.9.2 is not listed on CDN, using 1.9.1 instead (which is still not compatible with the code probably for the same reasons.) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='textfield' id='keyboard_input' onfocus="this.value='';"/>
<input name='textfield2' id='keyboard_input2'/>
```

Kind Regards,
JC

Comment: How sure are you that the problem isn't elsewhere? Where exactly does this code stop working?

Comment: This logic doesn't make a whole lot of sense: `if ($(':focus:not("input")').length) {` initially, nothing is focused, and in your sample, the only thing that can be focused is an input... so that condition will never be true. (unless there's a bug in 1.7 allowing it). Your code works just fine if you add something else that CAN be focused and focus it before typing, such as an anchor tag with an href attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the element that holds the focus with [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document#Extensions_du_document_HTML) as reminded [here](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/).
You don't need the event object either.

```js
var input = $('input[name="textfield"]');

$('body').on('keydown', function() {
    !$(document.activeElement).is('input, button, select, textarea') && input.focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name='textfield' id='keyboard_input' onfocus="this.value='';">
<input name='textfield2' id='keyboard_input2'>
```

Comment: Thanks Stphane, it looks like what i want, ill test in my site and let you know! Thanks :D

Answer (score -3):

I assume this is a bug in jQuery 1.7. The focus selector is supposed to find elements that are currently focused, but in 1.7, it's finding the body when nothing is focused. I would swap your logic around such that instead of looking for a focused element that isn't an input, look to see if any inputs are focused.

```
if ($(':focus:not("input")').length){
```

becomes

```
if (!$('input:focus').length){
```